Flame Game backgroundBuilder how to forward taps/clicks to widgets in background?
I am learning Flame using Flutter and have a idea for a game that mixes Flame & material widgets, like a listview.
Layout is 50% flames Game() and other 50% is a listview.
First solution tried was a Stack() that overlay the Game() with widgets.
It worked fine, but all particles effects gets "behind" material widgets. Understandable since stack will make ListView() as an overlay.
Then I tried backgroundBuilder like this:
Positioned.fill(
  child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    child: GameWidget(
      game: _game!,
      backgroundBuilder: (context) {
        return const Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Divider(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: ListViewCards(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
),

This solution shows the listview and particle effects are painting on top of the widgets as I want, but taps are not forwarded.
Are there any good solutions to make that happen?
Or maybe other methods to integrate a normal widget into the Flame Game()?
